# Join lists and sublists at the same time

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to join two lists while combining their two lists.

*Twist:* One of the lists can be empty (Count == 0).

Here are some POCO classes to show what I'm trying to do:

```
class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Below are some pictures showing exactly what I'm trying to do. As you can see I want to combine the lists and make sure everything is distinct.

Here's the code set up, so you can easily play with it: http://pastebin.com/Pa4dfebd

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Name` is the identifier of the location and the `ID` of the `Item`?

You could use this `GroupBy` approach:

```
List<Location> joinedList = dbList.Concat(guiList)  // put both into the same box
    .GroupBy(l => l.Name)
    .Select(locGrp => new Location
    {
        Name = locGrp.Key,
        Items = locGrp
            .SelectMany(l => l.Items) // select all items of this group
            .GroupBy(i => i.Id)       // group by item-id
            .Select(g => g.First())   // removes duplicates
            .ToList()                 // create list
    }).ToList();
```